# How does a lens affect the field of view in a mirror?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, lenses

If one looks into a mirror, he can see a certain field of view.

If he places a convex lens that magnifies (or a concave lens that does the opposite) in front of the mirror, but so that he can still see the entire mirror, will it affect the field of view shown in the mirror?

Comment: How large is this convex/concave lens? Is it large enough to cover the whole mirror?

Comment: @Kitchi The lens is large enough so that you can see the entire mirror.